# Validation Returns False, Then Continues Program Regardless

Tags: c#, validation

Edit add: The problem I was given amounts to making use of a text file that contains 18 differing account numbers. I'm given the option of making the program read it to an array or a `List<>`. Then the program should allow a user to input a number and determine if it matches an entity in the array/`List<>`, displaying that it's valid/invalid.

It took me a fair while to get my code to work correctly. Now, I don't mind that a bad input validation returning false is followed by the latter methods being run through, thus producing the second popup. It's rather annoying at times, however. It works fine, like I said, but I'd like to find out if there's a way to make it stop running through the rest if the validation returns false.

```c
private void ReadAccNums(int[] accountNumArray)
        {
            // Try-catch to prevent file error issues.
            try
            {
                // Increment num var.
                int num = 0;

                // Open ChargeAccounts.txt file.
                StreamReader accNumsFile = File.OpenText("ChargeAccounts.txt");

                // Read account numbers into array.
                while (num < accountNumArray.Length && !accNumsFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    // Put each item into accountNumArray.
                    accountNumArray[num] = int.Parse(accNumsFile.ReadLine());
                    num++;
                }

                // Close file.
                accNumsFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display error message.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        // Method to handle TextBox input 
        // validation.
        private bool InputIsValid(ref int accNum)
        {
            // Flag to make sure input is good.
            bool inputValid = false;

            // Get and validate accountNumbersAccessTextBox input.
            if (int.TryParse(accountNumberAccessTextBox.Text, out accNum))
            {
                // Did we get this far? Confirm input validation.
                inputValid = true;
            }
            // Display error message for accNum.
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a non-decimal, seven digit number" +
                    " for the account number.");

                // Reset Focus to accountNumbersAccessTextBox.
                accountNumberAccessTextBox.Focus();
            }

            // Return result.
            return inputValid;
        }

        // Method to find out if input
        // has a match in ChargeAccounts.txt.
        private int AccNumSearch(int accNum,
            int[] accountNumArray)
        {
            // Bool flag for matching accNum.
            bool accNumFound = false;

            // Index var.
            int num = 0;

            // Position of Sequential Search.
            int position = -1;

            // Get input from TextBox.
            if (InputIsValid(ref accNum))
            {
                // Read through array to find 
                // matching accNum.
                while (!accNumFound && num < accountNumArray.Length)
                {
                    if (accountNumArray[num] == accNum)
                    {
                        // Found a match? Yay! Access granted!
                        accNumFound = true;
                        position = num;
                    }

                    num++;
                }
            }
            // Return.
            return position;
        }

        // Method to determine whether input
        // matches an account number.
        private bool AccNumMatch(int[] accountNumArray,
            ref int accNum)
        {
            // Bool flag to confirm
            // matching accNum.
            bool accNumMatch = false;

            // Got a match? Tell the user.
            if (AccNumSearch(accNum, accountNumArray) != -1)
            {
                accNumMatch = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Account number correct. Access granted.");
            }
            else
            {
                // No match? Alas.
                MessageBox.Show("Account number invalid. Access denied.");
            }

            // Return.
            return accNumMatch;
        }
        private void accountNumberAccessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Declare array to be filled by
            // ReadAccNums method.
            const int SIZE = 18;
            int[] accountNumArray = new int[SIZE];

            // Get the account numbers.
            ReadAccNums(accountNumArray);

            // Var for accNum to ref.
            int accNum = 0;

            // Is our account number correct?
            AccNumMatch(accountNumArray, ref accNum);
        }
```

Comment: Step through it in the debugger, watch where it goes and spend a couple of minutes wondering why/pointing to variables to see their current values to answer your own wondering. Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: You life would get a lot easier if you use a numericupdown so the user can't enter non number input in the first place.. But if you must use a textbox, parse it at the start of all this and carry the int input through or return if the input is bad; you should nearly never need to use `ref`, ever, in your entire career

Comment: Done the debugger thing and it seems to skip over the InputIsValid method call correctly. Then it goes back to the AccNumMatch method, which called AccNumSearch, which called InputIsValid.... That COULD be the issue, having a chain of method calls. As for the numericupdown, that isn't even in the textbook I'm working with.

Also, regarding the ref thing, it returns false as to whether it's a match if ref is removed from their places.

Comment: *Also, regarding the ref thing, it returns false as to whether it's a match if ref is removed from their places* - I'm saying `ref` is the wrong thing to do in a "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" kind of way. It might well stop working if you just plain up remove it, in the same way that "my battery is goosed so my car doesn't start unless I jump it from my neighbor's car. If you take my booster cables away I won't be able to start the car" - well yeah, but if you fixed your car with a new battery/repaired the charging system/whatever then you wouldnt need to jump it all the time

Comment: Fair enough. I just went back to the chapter that went over `ref` and `out` and it definitely looks better to use `out` for, well, output parameters to later use for method runthrough(?) to complete a task.

Comment: In the narrow context of that chapter it might well look like a good idea to fill your program with OUT here, there and everywhere when you want to "return more than one thing", but honestly - this is OO programming. If you want to return more than one thing, you create a class that represents the thing you want to return and return it. You have `public class Person { string Name; int Age }` `public Person GetPerson()` not `public void GetPerson(out string Name, out string Age)`. I faithfully promise you in 10 years if someone says "name a C# framework method that uses an `out` parameter" ...

Comment: .. I'd wager the first one that springs to mind will be `something.TryParse` cos that's the only one you'll use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems and incredibly verbose approach to:

- the user types a number into a textbox
- the program checks it's numeric
- the program checks it's present in a file

If I was tasked to write such a code I might:

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  if(!int.TryParse(accountNumberTextbox.Text, out int seeking)) {
    MessageBox.Show("The account number text does not appear to be numeric");
    return;
  }

  accNumMatch = File.ReadLines("c:\\temp\\accountnumbers.txt").Any(line => line == accountNumberTextbox.Text));

  if(accNumMatch) {
    MessageBox.Show("Account number correct. Access granted.");
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Account number invalid. Access denied.");
  }
}
```

because there simply isn't any point in converting the file contents to number and then searching the number; simpler to leave them as strings and compare strings, after making sure what the user entered was a number

And if I used a numericupdown so the user couldn't even enter a non number:

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  accNumMatch = File.ReadLines("c:\\temp\\accountnumbers.txt").Any(line => line == accountNumberNumericUpDown.Value.ToString()));

  if(accNumMatch) {
    MessageBox.Show("Account number correct. Access granted.");
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Account number invalid. Access denied.");
  }
}
```

YOu can just convert what they entered to text and launch straight into reading the file and looking for a line bearing what they entered

---

I appreciate you might be learning, so using LINQ is a bit of a cheat, but even so:

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  if(!int.TryParse(accountNumberTextbox.Text, out int seeking)) {
    MessageBox.Show("The account number text does not appear to be numeric");
    return;
  }

  
  accNumMatch = false;

  StreamReader accNumsFile = File.OpenText("ChargeAccounts.txt");
  while (!accNumsFile.EndOfStream && !accNumMatch)
  {
    string line = accNumsFile.ReadLine();
    accNumMatch = (line == accountNumberTextbox.Text);
  }
}
```

I'll forego lecturing about using/making sure you close and dispose your file readers etc for now ;)

---

If you have to read a file into an array, you can use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() as a quick way to read a file. I won't use it here, but you can look it up if you want to see

---

If you have to read up to X lines from a file, into an array of ints, and then see if any of the ints are the one you seek:

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  bool validInput = int.TryParse(accountNumberTextbox.Text, out int seeking);
  if(!validInput) {
    MessageBox.Show("The account number text does not appear to be numeric");
    return;
  }

  
  int[] numbers = new int[100];

  StreamReader accNumsFile = File.OpenText("ChargeAccounts.txt");

  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length && !accNumsFile.EndOfStream; i++)
  {
    string line = accNumsFile.ReadLine();
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(line);
  }


  accNumMatch = false;

  foreach(int number in numbers){
    if(number == seeking) { //seeking comes from earlier
      accNumMatch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

You could break these into separate methods. Make a method that takes an input and gives an output:

```
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  int seek = ConvertToAccountNumber(accountNumberTextbox.Text);

  if(seek == -1){
    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
    return
  }

  int[] numbers = GetAccountNumbersInFile("ChargeAccounts.txt");

  accNumMatch = ArrayContainsNumber(numbers, seek);


}

//this is basically a variation of int.Parse/int.TryParse
public int ConvertToAccountNumber(string s){

  bool validInput = int.TryParse(accountNumberTextbox.Text, out int seeking);
  if(!validInput)
    return -1; //we will use -1 to signify invalid input, because no account number is ever -1
  else
    return seeking;

}

//File.ReadAllLines can help with this, as can LINQ Select/int parse
public int[] GetAccountNumbersInFile(string p){

  int[] numbers = new int[100];

  StreamReader accNumsFile = File.OpenText(p);

  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length && !accNumsFile.EndOfStream; i++)
  {
    string line = accNumsFile.ReadLine();
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(line);
  }
}

//there exist helper methods for doing this too, look at the Array class - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-3.1
public bool ArrayContainsNumber(int[] array, int seeking){

  foreach(int number in numbers){
    if(number == seeking) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I know *why* you used `ref` but you should avoid it. Actually the framework uses `out` when it parses text to a number and returns a boolean to indiccate the success and a number, but you can easily take the approach that something like `string.IndexOf` takes - it returns -1 if the needle is not found in the haystack. You haven't learned about exceptions yet (probably) but this would be an opportunity to use them too - throw an exception instead of returning a value if the input data is bad

All in, it's one of the few places where `out` might be reasonable in your career, so use it if you must (for academicc reasons, but don't use `ref` - ref is for methods that take a variable in with the intention of using its value before possibly overwriting it with something else. This is an `out` scenario, where the input variable shouldn't have a value and will be overwritten by the method) but

Comment: Apologies for the verbosity of my program, then. Have only recently learned method creation in a prior chapter and kinda like it to the point of taking the "divide and conquer" approach to heart, trying to give each little task its own method when possible. 

Regarding the unnecessary area where I'd converted the file contents to int's, alas, the problem has me needing to read them to a `List<>` or an array. And interesting to know about the numericupdown control, but it isn't covered by the book, sadly.

Comment: I also noticed that you used the public access modifiers for the method delegating alternative, which makes sense for easily accessible vars when needed. And about the `ref` and `out`, I've made a comment about it in the comments to my question.

Comment: Alright, took your suggestions with the method-focused program into practice but I still seem to be running into the double MessageBox output when input is not a number.

Comment: It must be because it's called twice; are you perhaps making a method that parses the textbox toa  number, and then calling it everytime you want a number, and then it puts the message every time? Study my final block of code; the only part that talks to the user is the very top level - the button Click, does a `int seek = ConvertToAccountNumber(textbox.text)` - it is this way because it means ConvertToAccountNumber is not tied to any particular thing.. It takes in a string and gives back a number. I can pass any string, from any UI control. It doesn't talk to the user, it just gives..

Comment: ..an account number or -1, and if it gives -1 then the decision is made by the Button_Click handler to show the user an error and return. Always avoid having lower level code do things like call to the user. Low level code should just do its job and give its output with the minimum of fuss. Your single Single Responsibility aim is good; but note the method is called `ConvertToAccountNumber` not `ConvertToAccountNumberAndBugTheUserWIthAMessageBoxIfYouCant` - it's thus more reusable and it has one simple job. Same for the method that reads a file of strings and gives back an array of ints

Comment: The public modifiers arent necessary in this context, but you're still learning - just make everything public because it's easier than learning all the finer detail of when you might want to use what, and everything will just work. More important things to be learning than access modifiers

Comment: Sorry, probably should have been more clear as to what I meant by double MessageBox output. If the input's wrong, it first returns the incorrect input message, then continues in the program to then output the "account number incorrect" message. This is where it's not **too** much of an issue but probably shouldn't be happening in the first place and I'd like it to basically stop after the validation..

Comment: Take a look at what I do -> 1) parse string to number, 2) store number, 3) check returned number, 4) if it's -1 then something is wrong: tell the user, and RETURN from the method (stop executing the process). The "do all your checks on your user inout to start with, make sure you're all good, then proceed or retuern if youre not" is a good, simple pattern that will serve you well

Comment: Ah, got it now. I was trying to see if I could get the same single return = halt to work in the input validation method but seems it had to be in the main button click method for it to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Indeed, return only returns out of where you are and goes up one level. throwing an Exception is how you return out of the very depths of everyhting